# custom drop down with image instead of default arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created one custom drop down with image to appear instead of default arrow. But the default arrow is still appearing along with the image. Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6pLJf/.

Here is my code.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <select name="country" class="form-control SearchBar">
            <option value="opt1">option 1</option>
            <option value="opt2">option 2</option>
            <option value="opt3">option 3</option>
            <option value="opt4">option 4</option>
            <option value="opt5">option 5</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
.SearchBar {
    height: 45px;
    font-family: 'gess_two_Light' !important;
    font-size: 19px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #B2B2B2;
    background-image: url(image.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right 10px center, left 10px center;
    padding-right: 35px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can't** actually edit the appearance of the dropdown menu, since that it is created by the browser, and every browser has his own layout for it. There are no CSS properties or JS functions to edit the dropdown.

To do what you want you should wrap some `div` elements indide another `div` and style them by yourself, controlling their behavior through Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `appearance` property. But some of the browser only it will support. [See the available browser support here.](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_appearance.asp)

```
 .SearchBar {
height: 45px;
font-family: 'gess_two_Light' !important;
font-size: 19px;
border-radius: 5px;
display: block;
border: 1px solid #B2B2B2;
background-image: url(image.jpg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: right 10px center, left 10px center;
padding-right: 35px;
appearance:none;
-moz-appearance:none; /* Firefox */
-webkit-appearance:none; /* Safari and Chrome */
 }
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PAQ6m/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there anyway I can create drop down menu using image instead of default arrow which works in all browsers.

Comment: you can't use normal dropdown. check jquery select box.

Answer (score 0):

You can style the top of the select list by wrapping it in a div with overflow hidden and forcing it to be wider than that div. Then you can apply your styling to the wrapper div and it looks like you want.

The only limitation is that you can't style the list itself, only the top part.

There are also lots of plugins you can use or write your own.

If you want to do this above, there is a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lg878/1/

The main code is this:

```
HTML

<div class="select-wrapper">
    <select name="country" class="form-control SearchBar">
        <option value="opt1">option 1</option>
        <option value="opt2">option 2</option>
        <option value="opt3">option 3</option>
        <option value="opt4">option 4</option>
        <option value="opt5">option 5</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and

```
CSS

.select-wrapper {
    height: 45px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #B2B2B2;
    width:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.SearchBar {
    width:120px;
    padding-right: 35px;
    display:block;
    border:none;
    height: 43px;
}
```